# How do I bind this service in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, android-intent

This is the code in my `Activity`. Initiate an **Intent**, then a **Connection**, right?

```
hello_service = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
hello_service_conn = new HelloServiceConnection();
bindService( hello_service, hello_service_conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

But my question is...what goes inside the Connection?

```
   class HelloServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,IBinder boundService ) {

        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {

        }
    };
```

Can someone tell me what code I put into **onServiceConnected** and **onServiceDisconnected**?

I just want a basic connection so that my `Activity` and `Service` can talk to each other.

**Edit:** I found a good tutorial, and I can actually close this question, unless someone wants to answer. http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iii-android-services/

Answer (score 16):

I would like to point out that if you follow the service examples provided by google then your service will leak memory, see this chaps excellent post on how to do it properly (and vote for the related Google bug)

http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android

Comment: The Link to this article is not available, but it can be found at:
http://www.mongrel-phones.com.au/default/how_to_make_a_local_service_and_bind_to_it_in_android

Comment: give link is dead now

Answer (score 5):

Binding to a service from an Activity should be avoided as it causes probems when the Activity Configurations change (e.g. if the device is rotated the activity would get created again from scratch and the binding would have to be re-created). 
Please refer to the comment from Commonsware on the following post on stackoverflow 
[Communicate with Activity from Service (LocalService) - Android Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908267/communicate-with-activity-from-service-localservice-android-best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

To connect a service to an activity, all you need to write in a ServiceConnection implementation is :

```
@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
mServiceBound = false;
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
MyBinder myBinder = (MyBinder) service;
mBoundService = myBinder.getService();
mServiceBound = true;
}
```

Here mBoundService is an object of your bound service. Have a look at this [Bound Service Example](http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/).