# Android 1.5, wana send info from "class extending activity" to "class extending service"

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I'm new to Android!

I want to create a background service, the UI contains EditText field (in which user inputs the time) and "start activity" and "stop activity buttons". By clicking start activity button, log info will be shown in log cat that service is started and a repeating log info message after the time interval specified by user will also be shown!
my problem is, I can get the time value provided by user in EditText field, but how can I use it?

```
public class ServicesDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ...

    public void onClick(View src) {
              switch (src.getId()) {        
          case R.id.buttonStart:
          Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");

              EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
          int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

              Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServicesDemo.class);
          startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
          break;
}}
```

(I have to pass `int i` somehow to `MyService.class` as I will use it in `onStart(Intent intent, int startid)`

```
public class MyService extends Service { .. }
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**
simply put the "int i" in the intent (and also slightly changing the intent too) in class extending actiivity

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
i1.putExtra("milisec", i*1000);
```

then change in class extending service will be:

```
value = intent.getExtras().getInt("milisec");
```

now we can use "value" variable!
regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use binding between service and activity. Searching here gives you some results:

[how-do-i-bind-this-service-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282359/how-do-i-bind-this-service-in-android)

[Service binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916253/bind-service-to-activity-in-android)

Comment: may be it is one way of solving this problem, i havnt checked it, but i have found another solution!

Comment: please, post it here as an answer to share knowledge with community.