# Hello Beacons detecting virtual beacon but not able to make continous beacon scans in foreground

Tags: android, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I have followed the ten steps outlined in the Hello Beacon app tutorial at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/hello-beacons/.

when i turn on the app for a few seconds (maybe 10sec) it tries to find beacons and lists the beacons found but after that even if i turn off the beacon or turn on new beacons there is no response or no new messages are recieved in the app . Unless i exit to main screen(home screen) and turn on the activity again is when the changes to beacons are detected. Is there some issue with the code or is it hardware.. I use nexus 7 2013(android 6) for the app. And beacon simulator for virtual beacons on moto g4 (android 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the tutorial, it writes out the beacons in onCreate(). This only happens once when the app is run. You need to modify the app to either have a timer to repeatedly get the beacons or, better still, cause beacons detected by the BackgroundSubscribeIntentService to show in the UI. You can do this by [binding the activity to the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723026/how-to-bind-an-activity-to-a-service-and-control-and-manage-the-service-from-the) and receiving callbacks into the activity whenever there are new beacons detected.

Comment: i think they are able to do it without binding the activity to the service because in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QeY9FueMow&t=1718s they are doing it with the similar code as used above. the code is https://gist.github.com/hoitab/9a68f87cd9e7d4da2e6c . I think nearby.messages.subscribe handles all the detection and starts the service when detection is successful . i just dont know why its not working on my device.

Comment: If your above answer is correct can you explain it further (i am not able to understand why the original codelab is working for them and not for me) Maybe i am missing something . Please help.thanks

Comment: in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QeY9FueMow&t=1718s at around 30:00 min there is a working demo

Comment: The demo is using different code. That code subscribes to nearby messages in the UI rather than service code which you can also do.