# RoboService exception on screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-service, android-orientation, roboguice

Hy,

I have an activity that is binding/unbinding to a service in `OnStart()/OnStop()`.
If I open a link from a list ( that opens in a browser) while holding the phone horizontally the application crashes.

I would like to mention that the activity is restricted in the manifest to portrait mode and is `singleTop`.

I get the following error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at roboguice.service.RoboService.onConfigurationChanged(RoboService.java:92)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3746)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I noticed that if the service is still bound when the orientation is changed then the app crashes.

My questions:

1. Is there a bug in RoboGuice 2.0 or I'm just using it wrong?
2. Is there a way to unbind the service before orientation changes ?
3. If for another activity I have the binding/unbinding in `OnCreate()/OnDestroy()` and I want to keep that binding until the activity is destroyed how do I do that , in these circumstances ?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but something I found useful while researching the same problem as the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2282359/2291 has some discussion about service binding and memory leaks.